# Procmail rule to change subject and forward a copy

Tags: procmail

I have an existing procmail recipe to forward a copy to my gmail account that is working well:

```
:0c
! myAddress@gmail.com
```

I have a second rule that is also working well (in limited testing) to prefix the subject with [OLD DOMAIN]:

```
:0fwh
* (To|Cc).*oldDomain.com
* ^Subject:\/.+
| formail -I"Subject: [OLD DOMAIN]$MATCH"
```

The issue is in my local email account I get the modified subject as expected, but not in my gmail account. How can I combine these rules or modify the forward and copy rule to change the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reverse their order; make sure the one which rewrites the subject runs before the one which forwards a copy to Gmail.

Procmail simply processes your `.procmailrc` from top to bottom for each incoming message, and stops processing it once a (non-cloning) delivering action is successful. The `c` flag says to clone the message (so, even though the clone is successfully delivered, continue processing the original copy).

As an aside, the regex for `(To|Cc)` should probably have a `^` anchor in front, unless you specifically want to match the text anywhere in a header line.

Comment: Thanks so much that does what I want in my .procmailrc file!! Question, I'd like to roll this out to everyone. Could I add the recipe to change the subject in /etc/procmailrc so it changes the subject for everyone. My hope would be this gets parsed first then ~/.procmailrc would get parsed next where I could have the recipe to forward a copy to my gmail address. I can always test this out, but hating testing in a live environment so figured it's best to ask first :)

Comment: Your exposition seems rather terse, but it sounds like it should work without any issues. For testing before you go live, maybe see also https://www.iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html